# Google Chrome Console Error

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-console

It's a Shopify App.Shopify that loads my web application on their iframe.
It works great on Mozila Firefox, IE and other browsers except on Chrome. When I try to load on Chrome, it shows following error.

> Refused to frame 'http://5281a995.ngrok.io/' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self'
>   https://* shopify-pos://*". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the app is not using SSL. Try adjusting your code and/or the callback URL so that your embedded app is served over `https://` and not `http://`.